# Which is best pdf viewer in android?

Tags: android

Which is best pdf viewer in android? Jio magzine which pdf viewer used?

Comment: This question is asking for off-topic resources and therefor off-topic for the programming Q&A forum Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ıf it is possible, you should use internal pdf view android.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
}
```

if you want to show pdf in app you can use third party library. This is the best
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: i actually like your answer, because you gave OP a way of doing it without a library. but you should be careful answering questions like these. [how do i write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) explains that you should `Answer well-asked questions` and `Not all questions can or should be answered here`

Comment: Thanks for your advice @a_local_nobody